# Apache Camel 4 - REST lowers passed headers in request

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

When calling an endpoint for a REST API running on Apache Camel 4 all incoming headers are lowered, for example when sending JMSCorrelationID header when calling the endpoint then I get jmscorrelationid back. I am using the servlet component for my REST API.

Spring boot version: 3.1.2
Apache camel version: 4.0.0

This problem started happening with upgrade from Spring boot 2.7.10 and Apache camel 3.20.4. Before no matter what headers I sent in the request they all came back exactly as in the request. No changes in dependencies/components were done during the upgrade only their versions.

Camel route:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MainRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").host("localhost").port(8080);

        rest("/api")
            .get("/hello")
                .to("direct:myRoute")
        ;

        from("direct:myRoute")
            .log("Incoming headers: ${in.headers}")
        ;
    }

}
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you provide some code, that is having this issue?

Comment: added into original question